# Extra scrollbar on modal of Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have looked through various questions on this site and other sites and tried their respective fixes but I haven't got any of them working for me. Whenever I open up my modal, an extra scrollbar is added. The extra scrollbar is of the modal, I know that, what I want to do is to hide the background-page's scrollbar so that it could prevent the background from scrolling. Right now, when the scroll of the modal is finished the background starts to scroll.

This is my modal's code:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalTitle">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="myModalContent"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>

                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default center"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>

                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SHc5P/show/)

How could I prevent the background from scrolling?

Comment: Please create jsFiddle for this issue...

Comment: In the demo you created, how can I get to see the modal ?

Comment: @RahulGupta Click any of the news items.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

to your CSS.

[Updated Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SHc5P/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but now the panels in the background are moving to the right side :/

Comment: I updated my answer. But there will always be a small movement with the content, since we need to hide the scrollbar to disable scrolling.

Comment: I have added `left: 6.5%` and now it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad you could figure it our yourself.

Comment: Thanks. :) If you edit your answer and add that thing, I will accept it. :)

Comment: Done as requested! :)

Comment: Hey but now whenever I open the modal, it scrolls to top.

Comment: This doesn't happen in the example fiddle, so it must be something in your other code..

Comment: That happens! Try opening the very last element. And see.

Comment: What do you mean by very last element? When I look at my last fiddle (http://fiddle.jshell.net/SHc5P/3/), I can't see that behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55969/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-sebsemillia).